# How to use a custom tile overlay in android?

Tags: android, overlay, tile

Making an Android application where a map is overlaid on to a google map. I used map tiler to convert my image into map tiles , but wondering how would I be able to implement this in my application?

Answer (score 1):

To add a tile overlay to your map you can do this:

```
 TileOverlayOptions options = new TileOverlayOptions();
 options.tileProvider(new UrlTileProvider(256,256) {
     @Override
     public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int z) {
         try{
             return new URL(your_base_tile_url+"/"+String.valueOf(z)+"/"+String.valueOf(x)+"-"+String.valueOf(y)+".png");
         }catch (Exception e){
             return null;
         }
     }
 });
 tileOverlay = map.addTileOverlay(options);
```

This example uses 256x256 tiles and the tiles should be placed on your server (set your_base_tile_url accordingly) in a path like /3/2-1.png (z/x-y.png)